# pointers and byte arrays in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to pointers and I would like to do a function such that add each byte in memory from an `int` variable to each cell in an `unsigned char`. Please, see code below

```
int main()
{ 
 unsigned char buffer[4] = {0};
 int number = 15
 unsigned char *ptBuffer = &buffer;

 return 0;
}
```

so the output would be

```
buffer[0]= 0,
buffer[1]= 0,
buffer[2]= 0,
buffer[3]= F
```

so

```
number = 15 => 0x000F
```

Answer (score 3):

A portable solution that does not rely on aliasing (which will probably annoy the optimizer) is to use some of the bit-operations C++ provides. If you are sure that an integer takes 4 bytes on your machine (but in production code you really should not assume this, as the size of an integer is not definite), it would go like this:

```
int x = ...;

unsigned char bytes[4] = {
    (x >> 24) & 0xFF,
    (x >> 16) & 0xFF,
    (x >> 8)  & 0xFF,
    (x >> 0)  & 0xFF,
};
```

The `>>` are bitwise right shifts. The `&` are bitwise ands (1 and 0 = 0, 1 and 1 = 1, 0 and 1 = 0).

You then output them e.g. by `std::cout << (int)bytes[0] << ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Although what you're doing seems somewhat pointless and smells like homework, here is what you can do.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(int)];
    int i, number=15;

    for (i=0; i < (int)sizeof(buffer); i++, number >>= 8) {
        buffer[sizeof(buffer)-i-1]=number&0xff;
    }

    for (i=0; i < (int)sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2)
                  << std::setfill('0')
                  << int(buffer[i]) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will create incorrect output on a little endian machine.

Comment: Of course, depending on endianess, the order of bytes will be reversed, but that's how it is laid out in memory. The question leaves a lot of room for interpretation what he wants.

Comment: Therefore your solution is not portable

Comment: Well, I thought the OP wanted to see how it is in memory -- I'll modify it then

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char buffer[4] = {0};
int number = htonl(15);
unsigned char *ptBuffer = &buffer[0];
*(int*)ptBuffer = *(int*)&number;
```

will give you buffer[0] = 0, buffer[1] = 0, buffer[2] = 0, buffer[3] = 15

It may also be done with this code:

```
int number = 15;
unsigned char buffer[4] = {0};
__asm mov eax, number
__asm bswap eax
__asm mov dword ptr buffer, eax
```

Then you could define it like this:

```
#define SWAP(val,buf) __asm mov eax, val \
                      __asm bswap eax \
                      __asm mov dword ptr buf, eax
```

and call it like:

```
int number = 15;
unsigned char buffer[4] = {0};
SWAP(number, buffer);
```

Comment: This does not give the correct output on a little endian machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but my understanding is that you'd like to fill an array of chars with the bytes that make up an int. Note that the results you will get will be platform dependent... i.e. on a big-endian machine you would get

```
buffer[0]= F, buffer[1]= 0, buffer[2]= 0, buffer[3]= 0.
```

To do this there are many ways, but the most pedagological in this case I think would be the following:

```
void read_int(unsigned char *results, int num) {
    int count = 0;
    char *num_bytes=(char*)&num;
    for (count=0; count<sizeof(int); count++) {
        results[count]=num_bytes[count];
    }
}
int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[4] = {0};
    int number = 15;

    read_int(buffer, number);
    return 0;
}
```

Note how you can cast a pointer of one type to a pointer of another, and how you can use a pointer like an array, and an array like a pointer.

Comment: what should i change in a little-endian machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling I may be wrong, since I would assume this would have been mentioned already if it worked, but this sounds like a good place to use a `union`.

```
union IntBytes
{
   int intVal;
   unsigned char byteVal[sizeof(int)];
};

IntBytes foo;
foo.intVal = 15;
// now access foo.byteVal[0], [1], etc.
```

I think that should be legal, and I would expect it achieves the desired result.